# Javascript Cursor

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cursor

I have the following script for a cursor trail, however the cursor image is appearing in the top left corner of the page and is not appearing as the cursor trail? What could be causing the script not to function correctly? I copied this script from: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex13/trailer.htm

I have tried editing the image paths(I originally used absolute paths to the images), I also tried disabling a previously used "plugin" which I was using for this trail

```
<script>
/******************************************
* Cross browser cursor trailer script- By Brian Caputo (bcaputo@icdc.com)
* Visit Dynamic Drive (http://www.dynamicdrive.com/) for full source code
* Modified Dec 31st, 02' by DD. This notice must stay intact for use
******************************************/

A=document.getElementById
B=document.all;
C=document.layers;
T1=new Array("wp-content/uploads/2012/10/meerkat1.gif",77,39,"wp-content/uploads/2012/07/meerkat2.gif",77,39,"wp-content/uploads/2012/10/meerkat3.gif",77,39,"wp-content/uploads/2012/10/meerkat4.gif",77,39,"wp-content/uploads/2012/10/meerkat5.gif",77,39,"wp-content/uploads/2012/10/meerkat6.gif",77,39)

var offsetx=15 //x offset of trail from mouse pointer
var offsety=10 //y offset of trail from mouse pointer

nos=parseInt(T1.length/3)
rate=50
ie5fix1=0;
ie5fix2=0;
rightedge=B? document.body.clientWidth-T1[1] : window.innerWidth-T1[1]-20
bottomedge=B? document.body.scrollTop+document.body.clientHeight-T1[2] : window.pageYOffset+window.innerHeight-T1[2]

for (i=0;i<nos;i++){
createContainer("CUR"+i,i*10,i*10,i*3+1,i*3+2,"","<img src='"+T1[i*3]+"' width="+T1[(i*3+1)]+" height="+T1[(i*3+2)]+" border=0>")
}

function createContainer(N,Xp,Yp,W,H,At,HT,Op,St){
with (document){
write((!A && !B) ? "<layer id='"+N+"' left="+Xp+" top="+Yp+" width="+W+" height="+H : "<div id='"+N+"'"+" style='position:absolute;left:"+Xp+"; top:"+Yp+"; width:"+W+"; height:"+H+"; ");
if(St){
if (C)
write(" style='");
write(St+";' ")
}
else write((A || B)?"'":"");
write((At)? At+">" : ">");
write((HT) ? HT : "");
if (!Op)
closeContainer(N)
}
}

function closeContainer(){
document.write((A || B)?"</div>":"</layer>")
}

function getXpos(N){
if (A)
return parseInt(document.getElementById(N).style.left)
else if (B)
return parseInt(B[N].style.left)
else
return C[N].left
}

function getYpos(N){
if (A)
return parseInt(document.getElementById(N).style.top)
else if (B)
return parseInt(B[N].style.top)
else
return C[N].top
}

function moveContainer(N,DX,DY){
c=(A)? document.getElementById(N).style : (B)? B[N].style : (C)? C[N] : "";
if (!B){
rightedge=window.innerWidth-T1[1]-20
bottomedge=window.pageYOffset+window.innerHeight-T1[2]
}
c.left=Math.min(rightedge, DX+offsetx);
c.top=Math.min(bottomedge, DY+offsety);
}
function cycle(){
//if (IE5) 
if (document.all&&window.print){
ie5fix1=document.body.scrollLeft;
ie5fix2=document.body.scrollTop;
}
for (i=0;i<(nos-1);i++){
moveContainer("CUR"+i,getXpos("CUR"+(i+1)),getYpos("CUR"+(i+1)))
}
}

function newPos(e){
moveContainer("CUR"+(nos-1),(B)?event.clientX+ie5fix1:e.pageX+2,(B)?event.clientY+ie5fix2:e.pageY+2)
}

function getedgesIE(){
rightedge=document.body.clientWidth-T1[1]
bottomedge=document.body.scrollHeight-T1[2]
}

if (B){
window.onload=getedgesIE
window.onresize=getedgesIE
}

if(document.layers)
document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)
document.onmousemove=newPos
setInterval("cycle()",rate)
</script>
```

Comment: That code is referencing stuff for browsers that do not even exist anymore.

Comment: That "Dynamic Drive" site should be avoided.  The code quality is generally terrible.

Comment: thank you for the replies.  Could anyone perhaps advise me on a site that provides good quality code please? :)

Answer (score 0):

This will make an image follow the cursor. I originally used it as a bookmarklet, hence it all being javascript.

```
var hi = document.createElement("img");
var att = document.createAttribute("src");
var sty = document.createAttribute("style");
var alt = document.createAttribute("onclick");
var ide = document.createAttribute("id");
ide.value = "hi01";alt.value = "alert('Hi')";
att.value = "http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/cartoons/pokemon/clip-art-pokemon-441770.jpg";
sty.value = "position: absolute;top: 0px;left: 0px;height: 100px;width: 100px;cursor:crosshair;";
 hi.setAttributeNode(att);
hi.setAttributeNode(alt);
hi.setAttributeNode(sty);
hi.setAttributeNode(ide);document.body.appendChild(hi);
var scr = document.createElement("script");
var scratt = document.createAttribute("src");
scratt.value = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js";
scr.setAttributeNode(scratt);
document.body.appendChild(scr);
$("body").mousemove(function(e){
    var a = e.pageX - 50;
    var b = e.pageY - 50;
    document.getElementById('hi01').style.left = a+'px';
    document.getElementById('hi01').style.top = b+'px';
});
```